# Объясните, пожалуйста, почему возникает такая ошибка при вызове метода

Tags: python, ооп, классы, type-error

Код:

```py
class User():
    def __init__(self,first_name, last_name,age,height):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.age = age
        self.height = height

    def describe_user(self):
        print(f'Первое имя пользователя - {first_name}')
        print(f'Последнее имя пользователя - {first_name}')
        print(f'Возраст пользователя - {age}')
        print(f'Рост  пользователя - {height}')

    def greet_user():
        print(f'Привет,{first_name}!!!')


my_user = User('Alex','Roman',30, 176)
my_user.greet_user()
```

Ошибка:

> output:TypeError: User.greet_user() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: Найди разницу между ``def describe_user(self)`` и ``def greet_user()``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оформите функцию так:

```
 def greet_user(self):
        print()
        print(f'Привет,{self.first_name}!!!')
```

Comment: Спасибо большое ☺️

Comment: Лучшая благодарность, пометить ответ верным ;)

Comment: @Илья  Если ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour